# Urllib2 - Returning sometimes nothing and sometimes page content

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to authenticate the user on the system, but I'm getting different responses from the same script.In some executions of the program it returns the content of the page (still not sure if it is authenticated), but sometimes it does not return anything.I tried to use the library "requests" but this the same result. Is there anyway I can test whether this user authenticates or not on this page?

```
import urllib,urllib2
user = "retatewud@maileme101.com" #Test user
passd = "Muranga21" #Test pass

data = {
    'dest':'REDIR|https://sac.uol.com.br/', 
    'skin':'',
    'user':user,
    'pass':passd,
    'url':'',
    'sc':'',
    'deviceId':''
    }

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
post_data = urllib.urlencode(data)
req2 = urllib2.Request("https://acesso.uol.com.br/login.html", post_data)
content = opener.open(req2)
page = content.read()
print page
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this script and after makingsubsequent request, I get 302 response code . I guess , there is some IP check associated with website(https://acesso.uol.com.br/login.html) which doesn't let you make many request from same IP.  So to deal with this problem you should use Proxy which send different IP with each request.

Python has a good sets of example to demonstrate using urllib with opener and proxy handler .

Go through . https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/urllib2-examples.html

Comment: I do not know the reason but in PHP subsequent authentication is possible without the use of any proxy, what I am trying to do is to pass a script in PHP to Python but I am having this problem, I tried to use proxy but there is some kind of block that does not help much.

Comment: Did you tried using proxies with python before sending request and it didn't work ? You don't need to use proxies for most of cases,  but I see in your  case where IP check on server is enabled , you should use proxy handler of urllib2.